# algorithm to combine similar tree elements (php)

Tags: php, algorithm, tree

I have a site on which I manage recipes.

A recipe is a "tree" but not really like a DoctrineTree since I store data in the jointure.

```
$recipe is an instance of Recipe
$recipe->getSubrecipes is a collection of RecipeSubrecipe
each subRecipe is an instance of RecipeSubrecipe and has some attributes
$subrecipe->getQuantity is for instance the quantity attribute
$subRecipe->getSubrecipe is an instance of Recipe
```

I am trying to write an algorithm that would allow to combine similar recipes (=recipes with the same id) of an array of recipes and sum their quantity. And keep the highest recipe only if no other subRecipes are similar to other recipes in the tree.

This last point means that if I have in my array:
Recipe C has Recipe B has Recipe A
and
Recipe B has Recipe A

and there is no other instance of Recipe B or Recipe A in the tree,
the result would give me just Recipe B with the attribute includeSubrecipes set to true and the sum of quantities which appear in both occurence of Recipe B + recipe C with the attribute includeSubrecipes set to false

This can become quite complex and I can only access subrecipes by looping though a recipes children. it's a relational database.

[image: recipe tree example]

With the previous tree (where the number is the id) I want to output an array of recipes with their quantity (say all their quantity is 1) and whether I need to include subrecipes (because if I merged subrecipes of a recipe, I need to include in my production the recipe ingredients but not its subrecipes):

```
1 - no subrecipes - 1
2 - subrecipes - 1
3 - no subrecipes - 2
4 - subrecipes - 2
5 - no subrecipes - 2
6 - no subrecipes - 2
7 - subrecipes - 1
8 - no subrecipes - 1
9 - no subrecipes 1
10 - no subrecipes - 1
11 - subrecipes - 1
12 - subrecipes - 2
13 - no subrecipes - 1
```

I am struggling a bit and getting confused with many loops and so on...

Any well made mind to help me on that ?

Comment: I don't understand what you want, sorry. You have a tree of objects. Each object has some properties. You want to get a table. "And keep the highest recipe only if no subrecipes are similar to other recipes in the tree" - what does this mean. Forget about recipes/subrecipes. It just confuses. What we have are nodes of a tree.

Comment: I've got your structure but I'm trying to understand your point. Do you want to re-index the md-arrays? Resort? Splice it? Split and merge? And what should define that "similar recipes" criteria? It's kinda vague to work on simulations.

Comment: Hi, sorry guys, I've added details. The idea is that someone could make a lit of end products to produce and I would give him a list of recipes to prepare. Some end products use the same subrecipes. So I want the same subrecipes  to display only once with a quantity allowing to produce the end products. and this can be quite complex at some points, hence my example